# How to connect codename one app to php/mysql database?

Tags: codenameone

I have been trying to connect my codename one app to PHP/MySQL database for a while. I have watched basically all the video tutorials I saw online to no avail.

I know I am to use ConnectionRequest but I have not been able to do this sucessfully. Can someone please give me a snippet of code that can connect a codename one mobile app to a PHP/MySQL database?

Comment: Can someone please tell me why I am being downvoted? I really need a response.

Comment: Because you need to show what have you tried, what are your errors... Not ask for "snippet of code"...

Answer (score 2):

There is now a [newer tutorial](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/connecting-to-a-mysql-database.html) covering this exact use case, the answer below is still valid though.

You need to create a webservice in PHP which is something you need to read in PHP tutorials.

Then to connect to a webservice follow something like this: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---connect-to-a-web-service.html

Generally its just opening a `ConnectionRequest` to the URL of the webservice and then parsing the result. If its JSON using the `JSONParser` or equivalent and if its XML use `XMLParser` or equivalent.

If you are stuck on something specific post a more specific question, e.g. I created webservice X that should work like that and return this... I tried invoking it in Codename One using this code...